# stopping, moving of mobile phone when vibrating

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators, vibrations

A mobile phone move aside when it vibrates. How is that happening ? and most importantly is it possible to make any changes to the vibration motor to stop moving when vibrating or any other methods to stop that ?
I have already read following links
[Would a phone move upon vibration in a completely uniform situation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61436/would-a-phone-move-upon-vibration-in-a-completely-uniform-situation)
[How does a mobile phone vibrate without any external force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17169/how-does-a-mobile-phone-vibrate-without-any-external-force)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61436/

Comment: You say that you have read the above post already, but the answer to your question is in there, by John Rennie, so I suggest you read it again or specify what it is you still cannot understand from that answer.

Comment: Thanx for the reply Michiel. I want to know that what changes should I do to stop that moving ?

Comment: You cannot stop the phone moving without changing the centre of mass. I suppose you could open the case and put lead weights inside, but this doesn't seem a practical solution. Alternative buy a rubber or some other high friction case.

Comment: @JohnRennie thnx for the reply. So to stop moving, designers of the mobile phone should locate the vibrator in a place where it satisfy the centre of mass concept. Is it correct ?

Comment: @user42571: Yes, but the designers are constrained by trying to make the phones as small as possible while still including as big a battery as possible. The vibrator gets fitted in wherever there is a space. As long as the phone buying public don't really care whether a phone moves when it vibrates, or consider a long battery life more important, this isn't going to change.